# Domain has disappeared, but Route 53 and UptimeRobot report it is still fine

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, amazon-route53

I registered a domain with 123-reg.co.uk. It sat there for 2 months and then around the 20th of October I transferred it over to Route 53. I am in the UK btw.

The domain arrived at Route 53 on the 27th of October and it was working fine until today.

I can access the IP address of the server, the server is still there and alive.

Ive checked the details in Route 53 - the A Records are all there, just as they were.

Uptime Robot is reporting that the domain is still live and active (they check from Dallas, Texas I believe).

The domain has disappeared altogether. Cant ping it, or get it through a web browser. I think it might of been wiped from our DNS. We have tried proxying though servers in America but we still cant get to the domain.

The domain in question is: chopsee.com

Can anybody suggest what has gone wrong, and how we can fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Contact Amazon support.

Comment: They are going to try and charge me money to open up a case with them, and at this point I am not 100% convinced that the problem is with Route 53. I was hoping to get an idea of the cause first before spending any cash.

Answer (score 4):

The whois database shows that this domain has a status of `clientHold`:

```
   Domain Name: CHOPSEE.COM
   Registrar: GANDI SAS
   Whois Server: whois.gandi.net
   Referral URL: http://www.gandi.net
   Name Server: NS-1245.AWSDNS-27.ORG
   Name Server: NS-2014.AWSDNS-59.CO.UK
   Name Server: NS-835.AWSDNS-40.NET
   Name Server: NS-86.AWSDNS-10.COM
   Status: clientHold
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Updated Date: 11-nov-2014
   Creation Date: 13-aug-2014
   Expiration Date: 13-aug-2016
```

The domain hasn't expired, so I suspect that your registrar has suspended the domain, perhaps due to non-payment or some other reason.  You'll need to contact 'Gandi' (or 123reg) to find out what's happened to the domain.  While the domain is in this status, no records will be served by the root nameservers, so you won't be able to go any further.

Comment: It also says `Reseller: Amazon`, so he actually probably wants to contact Amazon.

Comment: Ah quite right, I missed that -- good spot.